# SPHINX search php query, how to display results from an array?

Tags: php, search-engine, sphinx

Im beginning to learn sphinx search php api

after running this query

```
   <?php
  include('sphinxapi.php');
  $cl = new SphinxClient();
  $cl->SetServer( "192.168.0.100", 9312 );
  $cl->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_ANY  );
  $result = $cl->Query( "mimmi",  "searchtest" );

  if ( $result === false ) {
      echo "Query failed: " . $cl->GetLastError() . ".\n";
  }
  else {
      if ( $cl->GetLastWarning() ) {
          echo "WARNING: " . $cl->GetLastWarning() . "
";
      }

      if ( ! empty($result["matches"]) ) {
          foreach ( $result["matches"] as $doc => $docinfo ) {
                echo "$doc\n";
          }

          print_r( $result );
      }
  }

  exit;
?>
```

how can i display the results properly, it shows up output like this

```
2183 3262 5256 7812 838 1475 1701 6184 1816 Array ( [error] => [warning] => [status] => 0 [fields] => Array ( [0] => namn [1] => title [2] => identification_text [3] => id [4] => namn [5] => title [6] => identification_text [7] => description ) [attrs] => Array ( ) [matches] => Array ( [2183] => Array ( [weight] => 6 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [3262] => Array ( [weight] => 6 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [5256] => Array ( [weight] => 6 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [7812] => Array ( [weight] => 6 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [838] => Array ( [weight] => 4 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [1475] => Array ( [weight] => 4 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [1701] => Array ( [weight] => 4 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [6184] => Array ( [weight] => 4 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [1816] => Array ( [weight] => 2 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) ) [total] => 9 [total_found] => 9 [time] => 0.001 [words] => Array ( [mimmi] => Array ( [docs] => 9 [hits] => 46 ) ) )
```

i don't know what to make out of it, how do i display the results.

Comment: wtf? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821493/sphinx-search-does-searchd-has-to-run-as-a-service-to-make-it-work-with-php

Comment: yeah sorry, i made that question yesterday, but now i can't select accept answer for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point you want to take the IDs returned from sphinx and query your database with them.

```
<?php
     $IDs = implode(",",array_keys($result["matches"]));
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `id` IN ($IDs) ORDER BY FIELD(`id`,$IDs)";
?>
```

Comment: it that how you are supposed to do?, have you done this yourself with sphinx?

Answer (score 2):

Fields you declare inside your /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf will be available in $result['matches'] :

```
sql_field_string = my_field  # will be both indexed and stored
```

This way, there's no need to query your database